# Sending email with C# ASP.NET delays too much

Tags: c#, smtp

I use the following code to send an email with an attachment:

```
        // Specify the from and to email address
        using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("mailbox@gmail.com", To))
        {
            // Specify the email body
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Body = body;
            // Specify the email Subject
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            // No need to specify the SMTP settings as these 
            // are already specified in web.config
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            // Finall send the email message using Send() method

            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, nombreDoc + ".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

        }
```

Every thing works well, but the mail delays too much to **arrive**. I wrote in the body the time with `DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt")` to check the sending time, and it takes the mail up to 5 minutes or even 30 to reach the mailbox. 
What could be the problem o what I can do to delete the delay or, at least, make sure to delay it an **exact** amount of time.

For the attachment, I create an excel document with the library EPPLUS.
And here is the Web.Config:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" >
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" enableSsl="true" port="587"
      userName="example@gmail.com" password="password"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Comment: SMTP doesn't provide any guarantee of instant delivery.  Sometimes it takes time, especially if you're sending a large attachment.

Comment: I think the problen is not your code, multple factors could afect the arrive time as the network, firewall, the SMTP server etc..

Comment: Also, depending on how many you're sending, I would send them in small batches with a time delay between each batch.

Comment: @IrishChieftain Just one, maybe later can be 10 or 20, **max**. And the size of the file is, in this example, 5 KB.

Comment: Okay, I only do that when I'm sending hundreds or thousands. No need in this case.